# How is magnetic dipole "created"?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I know that the ***electric*** dipole can be created when the electron cloud is displaced realative to the nucleus. I am trying to draw parallel to this and to better understand this topic, so please help me undersant how the ***magnetic*** dipole is "created"?

Comment: Isn't that due to the electron spin? Whatever that actually is...